# TypeError: object of type 'Fraction' has no len()

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

I's adjusted it to add the self to the update but now I'm having trouble with my main where I'm testing stuff.

```
from file import Fraction
import random
def main():
    a = Fraction()
    b = a.update()
main()
```

---

I'm trying to make this for loop to work, its supposed to subtract the first number of a list by the second, second by the third etc and create a new list with those values. The `__init__` part works but then the update function is where I run into trouble.

```
class Fraction():
    def __init__(self):
        shape = int(input("How many sides does the shape have? : "))
        if shape <= 0: #doesnt work with negatives?
            print("Please make a valid choice (positive integers only)")
            shape = int(input("How many sides does the shape have? : "))
        numbers = 0
        print("Your numbers are: ")
        numbers = []
        for i in range(0,shape):
            n = random.randint(1,100)
            numbers.append(n)
        print(numbers)

    def update(numbers):
        long=len(numbers)
        for i in range(long):
            newnum = numbers[i]-numbers[i+1]

        print(newnum)
```

Comment: methods need a `self` parameter like `__init__` does. so it should be `def update(self, numbers):` probably, or make it a `staticmethod` if it doesn't ever need the self.

Comment: How are you calling `update`? The first parameter of it should be `self`, then presumably you need to pass in a list of numbers as well.

Comment: it is good to use `input()` outside class. This way you can run class with values from file or database or from hardcoded list. It helps to test code with the same values again and again.

Comment: you should use `self.numbers` to have access to the same values in all methods.

Comment: to create new list you have to create empty list before `for`-loop and use `newlist.append(newnum)` inside `for`-loop. Using `newnum = ...` you can't create list but you can get only last value.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: show how you use this class.

Comment: you have to use `self` in all function. When you run `a.update()` then it runs `Fraction.update(a)` so it assign `number = a` but `a` is `Fraction` instances, not list with numbers.

Comment: also you don't want to the `shape = input(...)` within the if scope but outside that way it looks more logical because a user would only think it has to have less than 0 for it be asked an `input` again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `self.number` to have access to numbers in `update`. And you should use `self` instead of `number` in `def update(number)`

Also to create new list you have to create empty list before `for`-loop and `append(newnum)` to this list. And later you can `return` this list to get it as  `b = ...`

```
class Fraction():

    def __init__(self):
        shape = int(input("How many sides does the shape have? : "))

        if shape <= 0: #doesnt work with negatives?
            print("Please make a valid choice (positive integers only)")
            shape = int(input("How many sides does the shape have? : "))

        self.numbers = []
        for i in range(shape):
            n = random.randint(1, 100)
            self.numbers.append(n)
        print("Your numbers are:", self.numbers)

    def update(self):
        newlist = []

        long = len(self.numbers)
        for i in range(long-1): # it has to be long-1 because later `long-1+1`will give `long` 
            newnum = self.numbers[i] - self.numbers[i+1]
            newlist.append(newnum)

        return newlist

import random

def main():
    a = Fraction()
    b = a.update()
    print(b)
main()
```

---

**BTW:** it could be good to use `input()` outside class and run it as `Fraction(shape)` so it could run with values from `input()` or file or hardcoded varaible. It is helps to test code again and again with the same values.

Comment: This worked so well! How would you have it so that the last number is subtracted from the first?

Comment: `self.numbers[0] - self.numbers[-1]` or maybe you need rather to substract first from last `self.numbers[-1] - self.numbers[0]`